# Making an object move up and down (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

I am making a side-scroller game in which a main sprite moves across the screen and has to dodge obstacles by jumping. I have made stationary obstacles but I need help making moving obstacles *that move back and forth*. How would I do this?
Right now I have this if else statement that moves an object up and when it hits a certain point, its coordinates restart to its original position.

```
if (movesquare1 > 20) {
movesquare1 -= 2; 
movesquare2 -= 2;
}
else {
movesquare1 = 145;
movesquare2 = 195;
}
```

movesquare1 is a variable within a function that makes the obstacle (a square). movesquare2 is a variable made so when the main sprite touches the moving obstacle, the collision system registers the change in position.

```
 (positionX > (439 - backgroundPositionX) && positionX < (492 - backgroundPositionX) && positionY > movesquare1 && positionY < movesquare2)
```

[The full game and code](https://jsfiddle.net/mittank1701/bh88gvho/)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask]. You're going to find it difficult getting help with this because your question (the code bit specifically) is too big. Can you produce a minimal (i.e. much smaller) bit of code that shows us what you want and what your problem is?

Answer (score 2):

You can use math.sin function. Put there your value between 0..1, and scale it.

Comment: Thank you! I will try it out.

Answer (score 1):

1) It's not a JavaScript related question, because you can have this problem in every language that can be used to create games.

2) my answer - as intro: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/math-and-physics/practical-use-of-vector-math-in-games-r2968. By moving to vector math abstraction from raw pixel/coordinates calculations, you gain a very  flexible, proven and handy tool for working with moving objects in 2D/3D

3) read some books on gamedev ('ai for game developers', for example)

Comment: Thank you! I've just started to program, so I'll see if I can understand and implement what's in the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to introduce a time variable to your game loop and update the positions of your movable objects in relation to the time difference between the current and the previous frame.

You could then determine the position of your movable square as a function of time.

For a quick experiment, try this:

```
var t = new Date().getTime();
movesquare1 = Math.sin(t / 200) * 50 + 100;
```

I recommend you to read through one of the many nice HTML5 game tutorials that explain concepts such as abstraction (make your game objects inherit common functionality), collision detection (run the collision detection at a fixed framerate, no matter the framerate of your renderer to avoid moving 'through' the path of a moving object between two frames) etc.